# Cracked.com Image Fading in Firefox (How to Disable Lazy Loading)

Tags: firefox

When I browse Cracked.com and scroll down (even after waiting for the page to load), the article images fade in instead of already being there, like on a static page.  It isn't a big deal, but it messes up my reading flow.  Is there a Firefox extension or setting to prevent this?  I use AdBlock Plus.

Answer (score 5):

> …the article images fade in instead of already being there…

What you are seeing is a frontend web development technique known as “lazy loading.” The idea is that if a page has—let’s say—20 images on it, the browser would only load images as they appear in the viewport. This speeds up page load since maybe like 3-4 images can show up in the viewport at a given time and is typically handled by JavaScript. Meaning that instead of the images being embedded in the HTML like a normal page, there is a pointer to the image in the HTML and JavaScript functions handle the actual loading when the screen scrolls.

So if you disable JavaScript the site won’t function and the images won’t load. And on many modern sites, 100% no content will show up with JavaScript is disabled since it is so commonly used nowadays it’s almost impossible to have a website without JavaScript being a core part of the mix.

For background details on the technique, here is [a page describing a jQuery lazy load plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) which explains the concepts/goals quite well:

> Lazy Load is delays loading of images in long web pages. Images
>   outside of viewport are not loaded until user scrolls to them. This is
>   opposite of image preloading.
>
> Using Lazy Load on long web pages will make the page load faster. In
>   some cases it can also help to reduce server load.

Coming at this as someone who personally does web development I am not 100% sure that is possible to circumvent it since the way lazy load techniques are implemented differs from site to site. So my educated guess is, no… What you are describing cannot be technically done or solved by a simple browser plug-in.

Also, you mention [Adblock Plus](https://adblockplus.org) as possibly having a setting for this. The reality is that tools like Adblock Plus work by understanding the consistency in the way—and methods—ads are delivered on the web. Meaning, no matter what site you go to on the web, ad delivery is fairly consistent and can thus be coded against to block said ads. And if there is a site with an inconsistency? The team at Adblock would make it a focus to figure out how to block ads on their site.

In the case of lazy loading, what is the economic incentive to create a plug-in or tool that can disable lazy loading functionality across millions of sites that implement the concept idiosyncratically and prone to even more changes when the site’s design is changed?

Comment: If it's implemented in Javascript for an individual site, and that site doesn't use any other JavaScript, then would disabling JavaScript for that site make the images load all at once?